# CreateIndex Issue while upgrading to EF6

Tags: entity-framework

Recently i had upgraded from **Entity Framework 5** to **entity framework 6** things which broke for me are:

1. **EF MiniProfiling**:
   if you were using mini profiling with EF5 you will have broken code as few of the                                         functiionality or variable names had been changed
2. After updating to EF6 it complaints you about change in your model and when you do 
   "Add-Migration" you will see all your index for primary key were getting recreated
    also its changing name of tables where you have one to one relationship
    so previously if it generates table name as TableATableB then it will rename table as
    TableBTableA dont know why

when you try doing update-database it will give you error saying something like 
index already there.

One workaround is to first drop all index (may be by coping code in down function and pasting it as first line in up function) and then recreate it.

Now I dont wanted to first drop index and then recreate it.

Is there is any other possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: You need to update to a version that supports EF6 (currently in beta) http://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.EF6

2: I think this will be fixed in 6.1.1 https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2167 - currently available in Nightly build